# phonegap cordova API window.requestFileSystem() LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT

Tags: ios, cordova, steroids

I'm using appgyver steroids (phonegap) and trying to save photos from the camera API to the app filespace so that it is not removed when I re-scan/re-load the app. I'm following the example from the cordova api docs (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileSystem), but I never get a response from

`window.requestileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, ...)`

The promise is never resolved/rejected. what am I doing wrong?

```
# in coffeescript
console.log "1. window.deviceReady. navigator.camera"+JSON.stringify(navigator.camera), null, 10000
_fsDeferred = $q.defer()
window.requestFileSystem(
  LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 
  50000*1024, 
  (fs)-> 
    console.log "2. window.requestFileSystem, FS= "+JSON.stringify(fs), null, 10000
    _fsRoot = fs.root
    _fsDeferred.resolve(_fsRoot)
  (ev)->
    console.log "3. Error: requestFileSystem failed. "+ev.target.error.code, 'danger', 10000
    _fsDeferred.reject(ev)
)
_fsDeferred.promise.finally ()-> 
  console.log "4. window.requestFileSystem(), Deferred.promise.finally(), args"+JSON.stringify arguments, 'danger', 10000
```

i never get to #4, the promise is never resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppGyver employee here – I created a simplified repro from your code, and it seems to work fine. See repro [here](https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids-repro-template/tree/issues/resolveLocalFileSystem).

One error I was getting when working off your code is that `JSON.stringify(fs)` was failing because `fs` is a cyclic structure and `JSON.stringify` cannot serialize them. If you just do `console.log(fs)`, you get the filesystem object fine (you might need to do a `location.reload()` in Safari Web Inspector to catch stuff that happens on application load).

Comment: sorry. I updated my answer on the appgyver forum, but forgot to do the same here.